# Alv OO program error Message no. 0K534

Tags: abap

Everytime i hit enter or any command button the program prompt an error message.

[image]

base on this thread http://scn.sap.com/thread/65856 i should declare my internal table
globally on top include.

Even though i already added all variable globally still the error is the same.

**Top Include.**

```
   data: gr_data     type ref to data.
   data: la_data     type ref to data.
   field-symbols: <gt_data> type standard table.
```

**Classs Declaration**

```
   me->get_data( CHANGING c_data = <f_tab> ). " Fetch Dynamic Data  

    METHOD get_data.
      GET REFERENCE OF c_data INTO la_data.
      move la_data TO gr_data.
      assign gr_data->* to <gt_data>.
      me->display( ).

    assign gr_data->* to <gt_data>.
    IF gc_custom_container is initial.
      CREATE OBJECT gc_custom_container
          EXPORTING
             container_name  = gv_mycontainer.
    ENDIF.

    if table is not bound.
       try.
           "// Create ALV Instance
           cl_salv_table=>factory(
             exporting
               r_container    = gc_custom_container
               container_name = 'TC_MIXING'
             importing
               r_salv_table   =  table
             changing
               t_table        = <gt_data>
            ).
         catch cx_salv_msg.                              "#EC NO_HANDLER
       endtry.

      "// Setup ALV Attributes
      functions = table->get_functions( ).
      functions->set_all( abap_true ).

      columns = table->get_columns( ).
      columns->set_optimize( abap_true ).

      try.
          column = columns->get_column( 'MANDT' ).
          column->set_technical( if_salv_c_bool_sap=>true ).
        catch cx_salv_not_found.                        
      endtry.
      "// Dispalay ALV Model
      table->display( ).

    else.
      table->refresh( ).
    endif.
 ENDMETHOD.
```

**and another question:**
 how to create structure dynamically base on field-symbol. is this possible?

```
ls_testvar like line of <f_tab>.
```

thanks and regards,
Mapet

Comment: Ehem, Did You specify a callback form, where the entered sy-ucomms are handled ?
This seems be missing, though i do not know for sure, if it must be using salv.

Answer (score 0):

Question two is possible, with some usage of runtime type services.

Take a look at runtime type services.

se24
CL_ABAP_CLASSDESCR Run Time Type Services 
CL_ABAP_DATADESCR Run Time Type Services 
CL_ABAP_ELEMDESCR Run Time Type Services 
CL_ABAP_INTFDESCR Run Time Type Services 
CL_ABAP_OBJECTDESCR Run Time Type Services 
CL_ABAP_REFDESCR Run Time Type Services 
CL_ABAP_STRUCTDESCR Run Time Type Services 
CL_ABAP_TABLEDESCR Run Time Type Services 
CL_ABAP_TYPEDESCR Run Time Type Services

You can get the type of the fieldsymbol and create a structure based on it, perhaps You have to iterate through fieldsymbol, if it is composed type  and add each component.

Comment: Hi icbytes,

     there error occur on table->refresh( ). class IF_SALV_ADAPTER~SET_METADATA. it seem the program error trigger everytime i refresh the alv.


Any suggestions?

Comment: For me the field symbol is not what the signature of the factory expects, the signature expects type table as changing parameter.
You pass a field symbol to signature.
That could be an issue.
You also can see some kind of Your apporach in this demo program
se38: 

BCALV_TEST_COLORS

Answer (score 0):

I agree, you should not pass a field symbol to the changing parameter for the table data! Use a global or static table. You should also use a typed table instead of data and create your field catalog in design time. This improves the performance a lot.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your `table` variable holding the ALV must be declared globally as well.

```
cl_salv_table=>factory(
             exporting
               r_container    = gc_custom_container
               container_name = 'TC_MIXING'
             importing
               r_salv_table   =  table
             changing
               t_table        = <gt_data>
            ).
```

You should separate data retrieving from your displaying code like this:

```
START-OF-SELECTION.
  gr_class->get_data( ).
  CALL SCREEN 2000.

PBO:
  gr_class->display.
```

Your display method:

```
METHOD display IMPLEMENTATION.
  IF me->gr_container IS NOT BOUND.
    gr_table->display( ).
  ELSE.
    gr_table->refresh( ).
  ENDIF.
```